# Awk iteratively replacing strings from array

Tags: linux, awk, gsub

I've been recently trying to do the following in awk -
we have two files (F1.txt F2.txt.gz). While streaming from the second one, I want to replace all occurrences of entries from f1.txt with its substrings. I came to this point:

```
zcat F2.txt.gz |
    awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next}
    {for (i in a)
         $0=gsub(i, substr(i, 0, 2), $0) #this does not work of course
    }
    {print $0}
' F1.txt -
```

Was wondering how to do this properly in Awk. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include some sample f1 and f2 contents along with your desired output? The latter should clarify what specific substrings you are after. Also, even though F2 is gzipped, this fact doesn't look significant for this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct the assumptions if wrong.

You have two files, one includes a set of entries. If the second file has any one of these words, replace them with first two chars.

Example:

```
==> file1 <==
Azerbaijan
Belarus
Canada

==> file2 <==
Caspian sea is in Azerbaijan
Belarus is in Europe
Canada is in metric system.


$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
               {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                   if($i in a) $i=substr($i,1,2)}1' file1 file2

Caspian sea is in Az
Be is in Europe
Ca is in metric system.
```

note that substring index starts with 1 in `awk`.

Comment: Thanks! This is very close, however, it does not read from a stream as provided in the example in the initial question if I see it right? But yes, the idea appears right!

Comment: the script is indiscriminatory where it receives the input. That can be achieved various ways, either `stdin` using a `-` instead of filename, or process substitution with `<(data)`

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
$0=gsub(i, substr(i, 0, 2), $0)
```

into

```
gsub(i, substr(i, 0, 2))
```

The return value of the gsub() function is the number of successful replacements instead of the string after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$0=gsub(i, substr(i, 0, 2), $0) #this does not work of course
```

GNU AWK's function [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) does alter value of 3rd argument (thus it must be assignable) and does return number of substitutions made. You should not care about return value if you just want altered value.
Consider following simple example, let `file1.txt` content be

```
a x
b y
c z
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
quick fox jumped over lazy dog
```

then

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next}{for(i in arr){gsub(i,arr[i],$0)};print}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

gives output

```
quizk fox jumped over lxzy dog
```

be warned that if there is any chain in your replacement

```
a b
b c
```

then output becomes dependent on [array traversal order](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting.html).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*